# Ionic --prod build for Android fails with ngc

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build a prod version of my app and running the command

`ionic cordova build android --prod` fails with the following error :

```
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
[19:55:39]  build prod started ...
[19:55:39]  clean started ...
[19:55:39]  clean finished in 10 ms
[19:55:39]  copy started ...
[19:55:39]  ngc started ...
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 133:13 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol App Module in ../src/app/app.module.ts
    at positionalError (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23471:35)
    at simplifyInContext (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23314:27)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23328:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22794:60)
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13352:70)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13937:60)
    at addNgModule (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22526:58)
    at ..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22537:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _createNgModules (..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22536:26)
[19:55:44]  copy finished in 4.78 s
```

Even when I ran `ionic cordova build android --prod --verbose` it spewed similar error.

Now as per the first error line - `.. Expression form not supported ( position 133:13 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol App Module in ../src/app/app.module.ts` it just has

`export class AppModule {}`

As a result I am clue less about the reason of the error!!!

When I run 
`ionic cordova build android` or 
`ionic cordova build android --debug`

it generates the APK within 20 seconds.

**How can I run the build command with --prod flag ??**

My locally installed Ionic details are as follows:

```
ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.9.1
    npm               : 3.10.8
    OS                : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : ....\Android\android-sdk

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Comment: show your app.module.ts file?

Comment: @David  a thousand KUDOS .. you helped me a lot. I accidentally commented out `{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },` line ..

Comment: No worries, that was easy ;)

Comment: adding --aot=false, its skipping ahead of time compiler, will also build